# Array from Firbease interpreted as Object in Polymer with dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, polymer, dom-repeat

I am using `dom-repeat` in Polymer for repeating an Array loaded from Firebase and I cannot figure out, why I get the **"expected array for items, found Object" error** as shown in the screenshot below. Here is the code I am using:

```
    <data-firebase data="{{cardsetList}}" requested-location="card-sets"  user="{{user}}"></data-firebase>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[cardsetList]]">
        <paper-card image="../images/trip.png" alt="Donuts" class="amber" >
          <div class="card-content">Test {{index}}</div>
        </paper-card>
    </template>
```

**Browser view & console**

[image]

**data-firebase** is an element I have created that loads the data from FB, as you can see in the console with success (the array of 2 objects is what I want to load

**Empty array before loading**
I checked if there is some not array data in the object I have before loading, but as you can also see in the console it is just an empty array. If I stop loading data from Firebase, there is also no error

**Meaningful array in Firebase**
I also checked the data in FB, it is represented as a JSON array (I can see that when I export the data, the data is exported in the array brackets [])

**Problem: Data gets loaded but the error persists**
How can it be that the dom repeat takes place (as you can see it is rendered) and also in the console there is an Array, but I am getting this error still?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is no support for arrays in firebase and that arrays get stored as "object" with integers as the key names.

```
// we send this
['hello', 'world']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}
```

See here:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

That looks to be just what you are getting back.

Comment: That's true, it is stored as an object in Firebase. But I am using this somewhere else in my app an it works, anyway there I using an array that is a child of an object. To my understanding, when you load again from Firebase, it is converted to an Array (as you can see in the console, it seems to interpret it as an Array, or not? also dom repeat is able to process it...).

Comment: Also, a quote from your link: "However, to help people that are storing arrays in Firebase, when you call .val() or use the REST api to read data, if the data looks like an array, Firebase will render it as an array."

Now I don't know how Polymer loads from Firebase, but as said, I experienced it is working in other places that it gets processed as Array (I am even using splice etc and it works fine).

Comment: Using a child of this, e.g. "cardsetList.0.card-items" (which contains an Array), the dom-repeat works and no error appears. It seems to have something to do how the data is resolved on the "highest" level from polymerfire...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the beginning the user doesn't seem to provided fast enough by the fb-auth. So as the user is empty, firebase tries to load data from a location that doesn't exist and thus is creating an object.

I added the following calculated binding:

**Function**

```
     hasContent: function(checkLength) {
         return checkLength.length > 0 ? checkLength : [];
     }
```

**And in HTML**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[hasContent(cardsetList)]]" as="cardItemLoop">
    ...
</template>
```

But propably I will have to think how I prevent that the queries/data-binding is made without having the user provided yet.

Also this seems to refer to [`firebase-document` defaults to `{}` before resolving #33](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/33)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not late , to prevent the query , remove your path and later on when you have your auth object set your path in js. 
So your query won't have a path and then later in your  tag and within the success callback of your auth, you set the path like below.

```
  signInFb: function() {
    this.$.auth.signInWithRedirect().then(function(response) {
      this.$.yourQueryElementID.path = "your path here" ; 
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {

    }.bind(this));
  },
```